# What is the meaning of the error : Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, supee-10266

If I try to apply PATCH_SUPEE-10266 i am getting error like : **Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?** How can i solve this error?

Complete error :

> patching file
>   app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.phtml
>   patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv can't find file to
>   patch at input line 720 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip
>   option?

My create_admin.phtml : https://justpaste.it/1eawg

Patch Error : https://snag.gy/hWXebp.jpg

Comment: Someone upvote. I have solved this issue, just replaced by fresh magento file.